# Vertx event bus can not send message to different verticle

Tags: event-bus, vertx3, vert.x

I am pretty new to Vertx, but I am pretty interested in testing its integration with Spring. I used Spring boot to boost the project, and deployed two verticles. I want them to communicate with each other using event bus, but failed. This is what I did:

1. In Main application:

   @SpringBootApplication
   public class MySpringVertxApplication {
       @Autowired
       MyRestAPIServer myRestAPIServer;
       @Autowired
       MyRestAPIVerticle MyRestAPIVerticle;

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   SpringApplication.run(MySpringVertxApplication.class, args);
   }

   @PostConstruct
   public void deployVerticles(){
   System.out.println("deploying...");

   Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(MyRestAPIVerticle);
   Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(myRestAPIServer);
   }
   ```

   }
2. In APIVerticle:

   @Component
   public class MyRestAPIVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

   ```
   public static final String ALL_ACCOUNT_LISTING = "com.example.ALL_ACCOUNT_LISTING";

   @Autowired
   AccountService accountService;

   EventBus eventBus;

   @Override
   public void start() throws Exception {
   super.start();

   eventBus = vertx.eventBus();
   MessageConsumer<String> consumer = eventBus.consumer(MyRestAPIVerticle.ALL_ACCOUNT_LISTING);
   consumer.handler(message -> {
       System.out.println("I have received a message: " + message.body());
       message.reply("Pretty Good");
     });
   consumer.completionHandler(res -> {
       if (res.succeeded()) {
         System.out.println("The handler registration has reached all nodes");
       } else {
         System.out.println("Registration failed!");
       }
     });
   }
   ```

   }
3. Finally ServerVerticle:

   @Service
   public class MyRestAPIServer extends AbstractVerticle {

   ```
   HttpServer server;
   HttpServerResponse response;

   EventBus eventBus;
   @Override
   public void start() throws Exception {

   server = vertx.createHttpServer();
   Router router = Router.router(vertx);

   eventBus = vertx.eventBus();

   router.route("/page1").handler(rc -> {
       response = rc.response();
       response.setChunked(true);

       eventBus.send(MyRestAPIVerticle.ALL_ACCOUNT_LISTING, 
           "Yay! Someone kicked a ball",
           ar->{
           if(ar.succeeded()){
               System.out.println("Response is :"+ar.result().body());
           }
           }
           );

   });

   server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(9999);
   ```

   }

But after I started it, and visit to /page1, message can not be sent from ServerVerticle to APIVerticle at all. If I move event bus consumer into same verticle as Sender, then event can be received.

Are there anything wrong here in sending message between two verticles? How can I make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You deployed them in separate vertx instance:

```
Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(MyRestAPIVerticle);
Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(myRestAPIServer);
```

Try this:

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
vertx.deployVerticle(MyRestAPIVerticle);
vertx.deployVerticle(myRestAPIServer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Vertx event bus is not shared across different Vertx instances like how you are trying ( But clustered Vert.x applications can do it). In your case change it to use a single Vert.x instance like below in your `MySpringVertxApplication`.

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
vertx.deployVerticle(MyRestAPIVerticle.class.getName());
vertx.deployVerticle(MyRestAPIServer.class.getName());
```